# How to use find_package to locate project targets in the same build-tree?

Tags: c++, cmake, build

If one has a workspace with multiple CMake packages (i.e. a project with its own `CMakeLists.txt`), and a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` building each package in a common build directory through `add_subdirectory`, is it possible to use `find_package` from within a package to specify build dependency to another package?

The packages are properly configured to be located by `find_package` (the targets are exported), but generated on their own subdirectory in the build location (e.g. `build/pkg1/kg1Config.cmake`) and thus CMake complains that `pkg1Config.cmake` file can't be found.

EDIT:

Currently I'm checking manually if `pkg1` is in the build tree or is available externally:

```
if (TARGET pkg1)
    # if in the build tree / being built
    if (DEFINED pkg1_SOURCE_DIR)
        set(pkg1_INCLUDE_DIR ${pkg1_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
        message(STATUS "pkg1_INCLUDE_DIR: ${pkg1_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "pkg1 was NOT FOUND! can't build without it")
    endif()
else ()
    # search if installed on the system
    find_package(pkg1)
    if (pkg1_FOUND AND DEFINED pkg1_INCLUDE_DIR)
        message(STATUS "pkg1_INCLUDE_DIR: ${pkg1_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "pkg1 was NOT FOUND! can't build without it")
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: No. `find_package` is for _external_ dependencies. If you have included a dependency internally to your build via `add_subdirectory`, there should not be a need.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yet I don't seem to access any `pkg1_INCLUDE_DIRS` (or any custom set variable) within any o the remaining packages. Do I need to explicitly set them on the top-level CMakeLists?

Comment: Those variables are _also_ `find_package`-only and shouldn't be used, anyway. At least, not when linking to a real _CMake target_ is an option.

Comment: The modern way of handling both kinds of dependencies is through their targets' properties. Ideally all you have to do is link to the CMake targets, e.g. `target_link_libraries(foo pkg1)`. Of course, that depends on the project being configured appropriately. [Here](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#if-you-want-it-done-right-do-it-yourself) is an example of what you could do in case it isn't.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with adding your own `FindPkg1.cmake` to some toplevel directory, and adding it to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and in those scripts test for the existance of the target. It may even provide you with a way of having alternative setups where it's possible to include some of the dependencies instead of building them in the same project, but in 90% of the cases this is more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: In my particular case, I'm just looking to use the include path of `pkg1` (actually it is a header only library). I did end up manually checking and setting relevant variables (cf. update on the question), though I'm still looking for perhaps a cleaner solution.